# How to import json data row by row to dynamodb using lambda function(nodejs)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

This is the excel file I create.

[image]

I turn that file to a json object like below in the frontend.

```
[
    {
        id:"123", name:'tom', country: "germany"
    },
    {
        id:"234", name:"ken", country: "sweden"
    }
]
```

I have an empty table at first
This is the ultimate result I want to achieve:
[image]

The solutions I found after googling:
1.Upload the json file to s3 > import json file from s3 to dynamodb
2.Direct upload the json file to dynamodb

But none of the results show how to actually implement it, by using lambda function(nodejs).

Question: How to do this in node.js(lambda function)?

Comment: Are you running API Gateway or using AWS SDK?

Comment: Api gateway >lambda>dynamodb

Comment: So I am figuring how to create my lambda function to do it

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a Rest API as S3 proxy and trigger event with lambda :

1. [Create a REST API as an Amazon S3 proxy in API Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html)

So you will setting up IAM Role Policy and your API Gateway to have access to the S3 bucket

2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html

Then setup Lambda permission to allow S3 event source. And update the IAM role policy of Lambda to have access to the S3 bucket

3. Update the IAM role policy of Lambda to have access to the DynamoDB table
4. Finally update your Lambda function code to have abilities on :

   - working with aws sdk
   - populating s3 event records
   - extracting every record object to get the s3 object info
   - getting the s3 object (the json file)
   - parsing the json file
   - storing the json data to dynamodb

It maybe help you to give the idea how to [Extracting data from S3 to DynamoDB using AWS Lambda + Golang](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/extracting-data-from-s3-to-dynamodb-using-aws-lambda-golang-bc0832ce5fbb)